# Converter JSON para map

Tags: json, clojure

Estou recebendo um `json` na *key* `:body` da resposta usando um *request* `clj-http`. Como transformar esse `json` em map?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Opa, resolvi aqui, usei a função :key-fn, como abaixo:

```
(json/read-str (return :body)
           :key-fn keyword)
```